# Where do I change the wording "membership fee total?"

Tags: civicontribute, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

I'm already in the automated workflow templates, but I don't know which variable I need to tinker about with so that I change the wording. I have a recurring recertification, that I'm processing as a membership fee, but the client doesn't want the receipt to read "membership fee." So, what am I looking for? I'd like to simply call it Fee Total instead of Membership Fee Total.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with Word Replacements, even for receipts. Under Administer - customize - Word Replacements.

UPDATE: Under Administer - CiviMail - Message Templates, then on the System Workflow tab, there's two receipts for memberships. You can edit it in there. If it's hard to find the wording use CTRL-F and search for Membership Fee.
Once in a while an upgrade will warn you that the template has changed and you'll need to merge the changes, but doesn't happen too often.

Comment: According to documentation that should work. Sadly, several test refreshes and browser changes are showing otherwise. I'll gladly chase down another method.

Comment: Ok will update answer with another option.

Comment: Sorry I reread your post and I'm not clear on whether it's just that you're not sure where in the message template it is (use CTRL-F) or whether you're saying it's not in the message template, in which case can you state what the exact wording is?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've been splitting time between this and mitigating a DDOS on another server. Your answer appears to be correct but the it's not working. I had originally thought to edit the receipt template but your solution was easier and should have worked. The goal is to make the receipt read Fee Total instead of Membership Fee Total. Any way we get there is fine with me.

Comment: Hope the DOS'ing worked out. If I send myself a stock membership receipt I don't see anywhere where it exactly says "Membership Fee Total". Can you maybe post a screenshot of the section of the receipt where this is happening?